Are Noahide males allowed to shave and beautify themselves without being overly effeminate?
I wish to know if Noachide males are allowed to shave, remain clean shaven and use skin moisturizers etc or is that an abomination to HaShem. Also are there any rules on how a Noachide should dress? I assume these would be covered in sexual immorality.

Cutting the corners of the head, tattoo/scarification, and making a bald spot could be covered under idolatry.
